# Converting a file into a music file?

Tags: audio, conversion

Are there any programs or tricks to converting any file, say a text file or a picture, into a music file like MP3 or WMA? To be clear, I'm not looking for text-to-speech, I mean literally use the bytes in a file as music. I searched for it on Google but all I found was text-to-speech software.

Comment: This might help you write your own, if you're experienced with Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787157/converting-raw-bytes-into-audio-sound

Comment: I wonder if you just want to listen to some "interesting" noise or are trying to do some kind of very simple (and easy to detect) steganography?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do, but I've not seen any programs to do so.

At the most basic level, it's possible to convert the 0s and 1s into two sounds with different frequencies and play them in sequence. Beyond that, one can perform an inverse FFT with the bits in the bytes representing different frequencies, or one can even do what modems do and modulate the amplitude and phase of a sine wave in order to encode the data as sound.

Comment: One doesn't need a special program for that; some audio formats (I would guess PCM .wav, maybe also .au/.snd) are as close as "raw" as possible, and even things like `aplay /var/log/syslog` can produce interesting sound patterns.

Comment: If you're only going one way, sure. But if you want to round trip the data, you're going to need something a bit more discrete.

Comment: Could reuse the mechanisms used by dial-up modems or C64 tape recorders, then.

Comment: Yup. As I described.